# How to make step argument dependent on configuration?

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

### Problem

I am using SpecFlow to create an integration test suite for a REST service.

I am running the suite in multiple different configurations. (I have multiple Build configurations, each with its own set of app.config transformations.)
In the C# code, it's very simple to check the configuration and execute different code based on it. I can simply do something like this.

```
[Given(@"I set the test parameter to ""(.*)""")]
public void GivenISetTheTestParameter(string parameter)
{
    if(CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
        this.testParameter = parameter + "Test";
    else if(CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
        this.testParameter = parameter + "Prod";
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it works the same way for every execution of this step, but I wan't to parameterize the configuration-dependent part of the step differently in every scenario.
Is there any way to do this in the **feature** file? I would like to do something like this (pseudo-code, this is not working of course):

```
If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterTest"
Else If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterProd"
```

Then I can use this parameterization in a different way in every scenario:

```
Scenario: Test 1
    If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
    Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterTest1"
    Else If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
    Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterProd1"
    ...

Scenario: Test 2
    If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
    Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterTest2"
    Else If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
    Given I set the test parameter to "ParameterProd2"
    ...
```

If the condition was implemented in the C# code for the step, this wouldn't be possible.

### Real world example

I would like to use this for integration testing a REST service. Let's say I use basic authentication, for which I need to set a header on my `RestClient` object.
I have a helper step for setting the auth header to a specific user name and password.

The tricky part is that I have multiple build configurations (let's say Staging and Prod), for which I need different test credentials. Also, I'm calling different APIs in the different scenarios of my feature, which also need different credentials.

So with the above introduced pseudo-syntax, this is what I'd like to do:

```
Scenario: Test LoggingService
    If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
        Given I set the auth header for the user "logging_test_user" and password "p4ssword"
    Else If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
        Given I set the auth header for the user "logging_prod_user" and password "p4ssword"
    ...
    When I call the LoggingService
    ...

Scenario: Test PaymentService
    If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Test)
        Given I set the auth header for the user "payment_test_user" and password "p4ssword"
    Else If (CurrentConfiguration == Config.Prod)
        Given I set the auth header for the user "payment_prod_user" and password "p4ssword"
    ...
    When I call the PaymentService
    ...
```

If I can only put the condition into the C# implementation of the "Given I set the auth header..." step, then I wouldn't be able to specify different user names for the different scenarios.

Comment: Can you give a little more context, and a real world-like example? I'm having difficulty understanding why you need to put this in the Feature file instead of reading it directly from `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`?

Comment: Added another example that shows what the advantage of having the condition feature file would be.

Comment: I'm looking for a real use case scenario for why you need this. You said you are testing a REST web service. What data in App.config changes requiring you to test the service differently?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, "why" do you want to do this? I have a feeling that the solution to your problem is much different than you imagine.

Comment: Added a real world example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the configurable data in your feature files at all. Instead, create a generic step whose definition reads the config file:

```
Scenario: Test LoggingService
    Given I set the auth header
```

And in C#:

```
[Given(@"I set the auth header")]
public void GivenISetTheAuthHeader()
{
    string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestServiceUserName"];
    string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestServicePassword"];
}
```

And in App.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="RestServiceUserName" value="..."/>
  <add key="RestServicePassword" value="..."/>
```

If different usernames have different permissions in the system, then consider using a Scenario Outline instead:

```
Scenario Outline: Testing the LoggingService
    Given I set the auth header for user "<Username>" and password "<Password>"

Examples:
    | Username | Password |
    | user1    | pass1    |
    | user2    | pass2    |
```

And they become normal parameters to your step definition:

```
[Given("I set the auth header for user """(.*)""" and password """(.*)"""")]
public void GivenISetTheAuthHeaderForUserAndPassword(string username, string password)
{
    // set the user and password on the auth header
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar for different environments, but we have a app.config for the tests which has several 'alternate' configurations for dev, qa and uat and we read the value of a named parameter from one of these sections.

We have something like this

```
<testingEnvironments>
  <testingEnvironment name="Dev" messageUrl="https://somedevurl/" isCurrent="true">
     <ConfigParam1>SomeValue</ConfigParam1>
  </testingEnvironment>
  <testingEnvironment name="QA" messageUrl="https://somedqaurl/" isCurrent="false">
     <ConfigParam1>SomeValueInQA</ConfigParam1>
  </testingEnvironment>
  <testingEnvironment name="UAT" messageUrl="https://someuaturl/" isCurrent="false">
     <ConfigParam1>SomeValueUAT</ConfigParam1>
  </testingEnvironment>
</testingEnvironments>
```

we select the config based on the value of the `isCurrent` attribute, but you could just select it on the name based on an environment variable.

Then your tests are ignorant of the exact values used then just refer to `ConfigParam1`

based on your real world example I don't like the implementation detail in the tests (what if you use some other authentication mechanism) and would restructure my specifications like this:

```
Scenario: Test LoggingService
    Given I am the logging service default user for the current environment     
    When I call the LoggingService
    ...

Scenario: Test payment Service
    Given I am the payment service default user for the current environment     
    When I call the PaymentService
    ...
```

and would add config something like this:

```
  <testingEnvironment name="DEV" messageUrl="https://somedevurl/" isCurrent="false">
     <userCredentials>
          <LoggingService>
             <defaultUser name="logging_test_user" password="p4ssword" />                 
          </LoggingService>
          <PaymentService>
             <defaultUser name="payment_test_user" password="p4ssword" />                 
          </PaymentService>
     </userCredentials>         
  </testingEnvironment>
  <testingEnvironment name="UAT" messageUrl="https://someuaturl/" isCurrent="false">
     <userCredentials>
          <LoggingService>
             <defaultUser name="logging_prod_user" password="p4ssword" />                 
          </LoggingService>
          <PaymentService>
             <defaultUser name="payment_prod_user" password="p4ssword" />                 
          </PaymentService>
     </userCredentials>         
  </testingEnvironment>
```

your individual steps could then call a common step to set the actual header values

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve what you want with a scenario outline and tagged examples, but then you would have to run only some tests in some environments:

```
Scenario Outline: Testing the LoggingService
    Given I set the auth header for user "<Username>" and password "<Password>"

@Production
Examples:
    | Username          | Password |
    | logging_prod_user | p4ssword |
@Test
Examples:
    | Username          | Password  |
    | logging_test_user | p4assword |
```

then configure your test runner to run only tests in certain categories (either `Test` or `Production`)

if you are using nunit (or XUnit or any other test runner that defaults to using row tests for running scenario outlines) as your test runner, be aware of [this issue](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/449)

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should always be the same -- a test with an "if" in it is at least two tests. The proper way to tackle this is to isolate the system under test such that it takes a parameter (or is otherwise provided with a value) that represents the configuration value, then write tests for all of the applicable scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the feature:

```
Scenario: Test LoggingService
    Given I set the auth header with valid user and password
    When I call the LoggingService
    # ...
```

Set the `App.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EnvironmentUserName" value="..."/>
    <add key="EnvironmentPassword" value="..."/>
    <!-- ... -->
</appSettings>
```

and implement the step as:

```
public void GivenISetTheAuthHeader()
{
    string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentUserName"];
    string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentPassword"];
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this already in a bit different way, but this way the credentials cannot depend on what scenario you're calling the step from, so you must implement two different steps.

Comment: Maybe you need scoped bindings: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings